# Acquire CSRF token for chrome extension from django

Tags: django, post, google-chrome-extension, csrf, django-csrf

I want to use a POST request to send data from chrome extension to a Django app. However, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error. How do I acquire the CSRF token from Django to send as a header along with the chrome extension?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

go to inspect element storage cookies

[image]